# How do I align my image in the ReactJS in the ProfilePage.jsx file? And how do I add a double border?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

[image]

```
return (
    <div className = "mx-auto w-11/12 md:w-2/4 py-8 px-4 md:px-8">
      <div className="flex border flex-col items-center md:flex-row md:items-start border-blue-400 px-3 py-4">
        <div
          style={{
            background: `url(${photoURL || 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dqcsk8rsc/image/upload/v1577268053/avatar-1-bitmoji_upgwhc.png'})  no-repeat center center`,
            backgroundSize: "cover",
            height: "110px",
            width: "110px",
            borderRadius: "80px",
            border: 'solid 6.5px #E6CDF2',
```

Hi I'm trying to align this picture using AlignContent and justifyContent but nothing works. This is my code in ProfilePage.jsx file for designing the image. I am not sure how to align it. Also wondering how (if possible) I can add a double border here.

Comment: I recommend you to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for your image and all elements beneath to align them in the middle of the screen.

Comment: Add ```margin: 'auto'``` to the style attribute of the div where you are adding background properties.. Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/csstransition-component-forked-ieiu6

Comment: @VISHRUTGOEL, Also make sure whenever you post a question in stack overflow, don't forget to align your code.. You have missed all the closing tags in the above question..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use AlignItems instead of AlignContent.